# How can I find out which docker image is being accessed by Jenkins from aws ecr?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am running some test data against a docker image in Jenkins. The docker image contains a database with data in it, which the test data is being run against.

I am struggling to find the database or ecr/docker image from aws.

I have some Jenkins logs that indicates (I think) where the docker image is sitting, though I could be wrong. Here are the logs:

```
FROM 361053.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/cjjs/sampledb
```

(I have omitted some numbers and characters for secirity).

I have logged into aws ECR in my terminal, and have tried `aws ecr describe-repositories`, but I can't find anything indicating the above.

Any suggestions on how I can find the above docker image `sampledb` ? Thanks

Comment: The 361053 (missing some numbers) is the account ID and cjjs/sampledb is the repository name.

Comment: Amazing, thank you @luk2302- you're completely right it is missing some numbers, I took it out for security, just in case but perhaps there was no point in doing that.